# db_query gives PDO Exception "General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value:" when I try to update table

Tags: database

I'm trying to execute the following SQL query

```
$tweet_id_int = intval($tweet->id);
$result = db_query("INSERT INTO tweetsDB (handle,tweet,time_string,tweetid) VALUES     ('%v1','%v2','%v3','%v4')", array('%v1'=>$twitter_handle,'%v2'=>$tweet->text,'%v3'=>$tweet->created_at,'%v4'=> $tweet_id_int));
```

from inside a Drupal module and getting the error

```
    PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '%v4' for column 'TweetID' at row 1: INSERT INTO tweetsDB (handle,tweet,time_string,tweetid) VALUES ('%v1','%v2','%v3','%v4'); Array ( [%v1] => davecohen [%v2] => taking it easy - Rosh Hashana [%v3] => Fri Sep 14 08:06:08 +0000 2007 [%v4] => 267918272 )
```

handle, tweet and time_string are VARCHAR

tweetid is BIGINT

The "TweetID" is the value I received from calling the Twitter API earlier to fetch some tweets. Twitter API returns the Tweet ID as a string, so I called 'intval' before passing it to the SQL query. If I try running the same query into the MySQL database directly via the Sequel Pro console

```
 INSERT INTO tweetsDB (handle,tweet,time_string,tweetid) VALUES ('davecohen','taking it easy - Rosh Hashana','Fri Sep 14 08:06:08 +0000 2007','267918272')
```

Then I get no problems at all.

Any help here would be MUCH appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Drupal API on [`db_query`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query/7):

> Do not use this function for INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE queries. Those should be handled via db_insert(), db_update() and db_delete() respectively.

The recommended method:

```
// Insert values returned from Twitter API.
$tweetsdb_id = db_insert('tweetsDB')
->fields(array(
  'handle' => $handle,
  'tweet' => $tweet,
  'time_string' =>$time_string,
  'tweetid' => $id,
))
->execute();
```